# App Transport Setting exception domains not working xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7, app-transport-security

How do I set an exception domain?
I want to load a map ttile eg from the domain http://map1.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov.

I have added an exception but it's not working.  Unless I use set "abritrary loads" instead I get the error "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

[image]

UPDATE;  attempt 2:  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include subdomains for this to work with all nasa.gov subdomains by also adding `NSIncludesSubdomains`. Also, I would add `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`.  Try getting your Info.plist to use the following settings under nasa.gov entry:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your domains have to be the keys of dictionaries which contain the BOOL `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` with the value `YES`.

For every domain, add a dictionary item to the Exception Domains, where the key is the domain in question. Set NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads to YES to disable the HTTPS requirement for that domain.

Comment: thanks so much @FelixSFD very helpful. I changed the domain to a dictionary, and added the NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads as a bool YES underneath it. (see my screenshot above). Is that what you mean? Or am I missing something? It's not working as yet.

Comment: @DimitriT i guess you need to remove the "Allow Arbitary Loads" key instead of setting it to NO. But i can't verify this at the moment

Comment: how strange, that is not working either. Thank you for the suggestion though.